# FireDAC Explorer(FDExplorer) how secure is it? how is the data stored?

Tags: delphi, firedac

If a connection is defined in the [FDExplorer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/FDExplorer), how secure is the connection data?

Is the connection deployed with the compiled program?
Are all the connections compiled into the program?
Is the data encrypted?

update:
FireDAC store the data in a plain text Ini file.

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\FireDAC\FDConnectionDefs.ini

To distribute data with the program, the ini file needs to be distribute along side.Not sure about the location it needs to be at.

Comment: What is Fire Duc Explorer?

Comment: yes, misspelled the header, but the tag was clear. and the link was there.

Comment: Might I suggest you re-read your posts before committing them. Regarding the block quote in your edit. What are you quoting?

Comment: What are your security goals anyway? Presumably you aren't going to expose your db to the wild? You'll surely use a multi tier architecture as is best practice.

Comment: A connection string stores more then the database name.It contains credentials to login.

Comment: Yes indeed. You aren't planning on passing that over HTTP on the internet are you?

Comment: You don't need to include the user credentials in the connection data, so you can supply them at r/t from encrypted data in your app, or you can require the user to enter them.

Comment: @MartynA And then pass them unencrypted over the internet? And have the data pass back and forth unencrypted? The DB should not be exposed in the first place.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Not necessarily, could be an entirely in-house system where the internet isn't a factor.  In fact I wouldn't be surprised if the majority of Delphi DB apps are still bespoke in-house ones, despite it no longer being Windows-only.

Comment: @MartynA Either it needs to be secured, or it doesn't. If it needs to be secured, then exposing the DB is a bad plan.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I don't think it's as black and white as that.  If, as mine was, the middle tier server is locked in a secure room with no physical connection to the internet, then "exposing" the data in the db doesn't arise.  But the users' credentials may still be sensitive, relative to other users.  But in any case, the OP seems to be aware of the risks ...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The specification of a component needs to write down what security measures was made, and where are the vulnerabilities to watch out for. if the data is stored in memory as plain text string, that lets a memory sniffing program easy target to extract the data also. i am asking to know the limits.